# #NULL is not a valid value for Int32

Tags: c#, .net

While I am debugging the code,  I am getting the error `#NULL is not a valid value for Int32`.

```
private void satelliteComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Helper.SetWaitCursor();
    if (satelliteComboBox.SelectedValue != null)
    {
        var satelliteId = Convert.ToInt32(satelliteComboBox.SelectedValue);
        satelliteStatusUserControl.DataSource = 
            _satelliteStatusBusinessService.GetSingleSatellite(
                new Dictionary<string, object> { { "SatelliteID", satelliteId } }, true);
        //2012.07.07 get colors for all machine status
        satelliteStatusUserControl.DataSource.DefectColors = 
                  _satelliteStatusBusinessService.GetDefectColors().ToList();

        foreach (var defectColor in 
                      satelliteStatusUserControl.DataSource.DefectColors)
        {
            MachineStatusCtrl.AddMachineStatusColors(
                         defectColor.DefectTypeID, 
                         defectColor.DefectType, 
                         defectColor.OEEColor);
        }
        //2012.07.07
        satelliteStatusUserControl.DataBind();
    }
    Helper.SetDefaultCursor();
}
```

I am getting this error in my `foreach` loop

UPDATE: Here is the implementation for `AddMachineStatusColors`

```
public static void AddMachineStatusColors(int statusColorId, string StatusName, string oeeColor)
{         
    MacStatusColors macStatusColor;

    //add dummy colors with unknow till the next defectId so that it will be easy to get color later while painting.            
    for(int Index = StatusColors.Count; Index < statusColorId ; Index++)
    {
        macStatusColor = new MacStatusColors();
        StatusColors.Add(macStatusColor);
    }

    macStatusColor = new MacStatusColors();
    macStatusColor.DefectTypeID = statusColorId;
    macStatusColor.DefectType = StatusName;
    macStatusColor.OEEColor1 = ControlPaint.Dark(getColorFromString(oeeColor));
    macStatusColor.OEEColor2 = ControlPaint.Light(getColorFromString(oeeColor));
    StatusColors.Add(macStatusColor);
}



    public static Color getColorFromString(string oeeColor)
    {            
        if (oeeColor[0] != '#') { oeeColor = '#' + oeeColor; }
        return System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(oeeColor);
    }
```

Comment: Please debug first and then tell us on which line the error happens. Also, what's the value of `satelliteComboBox.SelectedValue`.

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: on which line of code you are getting this error?

Comment: i am getting this error in for each loop  defectColor.OEEColor when i am setting the colour as null in sql

Comment: Are you binding the list from a database query? Does the query return `DBNull.Value`, i.e. `NULL` as one of the results?

Comment: Did you mean this [Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx) then you should check at `Color.Empty` rather

Comment: yes i am binding it in database i gave null in OEEclour column and it is throwing this exception

Comment: What do you want to do with `Null` colours then? Do you want to ignore them? One option is to look for the `#NULL` value (either directly with something like a basic `Convert.ToString(satelliteComboBox.SelectedValue) != "#NULL"`or testing for `DBNull.Value`) when loading, and then mapping that to a `OEEColor.Null` value to indicate that's a null colour in *your application*

Comment: Please show us the implementation of `AddMachineStatusColors` in your question!

Answer (score 2):

Well, `defectColor.OEEColor` seems to be `null` and your data model does not permit the value to be `null`. Three possible solutions:

1. Change the data model so the field can be `null`
2. Make sure `defectColor.OEEColor` is not `null`
3. Change the line to:

   `MachineStatusCtrl.AddMachineStatusColors(..., ..., defectColor.OEEColor ?? <default value>);`

With `<default value>` being 0 or any other `int` value that you want to use to indicate "color is `null`".

---

You added the code for the `AddMachineStatusColors` method. Thanks, but still I say that your code assumes that `defectColor.OEEColor` is not `null`. There are at least two lines in your code where I assume that `defectColor.OEEColor` may not be `null`:

```
macStatusColor.OEEColor1 = ControlPaint.Dark(getColorFromString(oeeColor));
macStatusColor.OEEColor2 = ControlPaint.Light(getColorFromString(oeeColor));
```

Show the code for `getColorFromString`, please, or tell us exactly on which line in your `AddMachineStatusColors` method the error occurs!

---

OK, now we're getting somewhere. `defectColor.OEEColor` contains *the string value* "null"!! That means, `defectColor.OEEColor` itself *is not `null`*, but it *contains the word "null"*.

Because of this, the following line turns the word "null" into "#null" (thus your strange question headline about "#null is not a valid value..."):

```
if (oeeColor[0] != '#') { oeeColor = '#' + oeeColor; }
```

After that `oeeColor` has the value "#null" and then the following line (I suppose, as you've not given us any details on which line the exception really occurs...) throws an error:

```
return System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(oeeColor);
```

**You must make sure that `defectColor.OEEColor` is neither `null` (i.e. "doesn't have a value") and that the value it has is a valid HTML color string!**

Comment: here in option 3 i cant able to add ?? <default value> (this code) it is throwing exception

Comment: option 2 i cant do it because i need both null and valid colours in my database

Comment: Did you read what you should write for `<default value>`? Please show the implementation for the `AddMachineStatusColors` method, so we can help you further.

Comment: public void AddMachineStatus(DateTime startDateTime, DateTime endDateTime, int defectTypeId, bool status);

Comment: The *code*, not the *declaration*. Also, this is another declaration than the one you're using in your code. I can't see and `DateTime`s in your code. Please try to be consistent in what you post.

Comment: I'm trying, but you are not providing me enough information ;-) Please post the implementation of the `AddMachineStatusColors` method! Change your question to include that code, do not post it as a comment if possible.

Comment: My "good reply" is: In the code you added to your question, on which line does the error occur? I still say that `oeeColor` is `null`, but you're assuming in many places that it is not. I don't see anything database-related here... I presume the error occurs on this line `getColorFromString(oeeColor)`. And here the color string **must have a value and can not be `null`**, so make sure that `oeeColor` is not `null`!!

Comment: but my client asking me to put the null value and try to solve the error which is happening

Comment: var sqlQuery = "Select defectTypeID, DefectType,  OEEColours From [DefectTypes] where OEECategory != 0";

Comment: i have post u the getcolourfromstring code please check it and give me the replay

Answer (score 0):

If the integer you're receiving might be null, it's probably a `Nullable<Integer>` which means it will have a `.HasValue` property...

```
foreach (var defectColor in satelliteStatusUserControl.DataSource.DefectColors)
{
    if(defectColor.OEEColor.HasValue) {
        MachineStatusCtrl.AddMachineStatusColors(defectColor.DefectTypeID, defectColor.DefectType, defectColor.OEEColor);
    } else {
        //Use a default
        MachineStatusCtrl.AddMachineStatusColors(defectColor.DefectTypeID, defectColor.DefectType, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int? satelliteId;
int i;
if (satelliteComboBox.SelectedValue != null && int.tryParse(satelliteComboBox.SelectedValue, out i))
{
    satellideId = i;
}
```